# Recoding malloc and size of pages

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

I am recoding malloc **with the mmap function**. I am using the best-fit algorithm and I am able to allocate and desallocate in one page. My malloc function is working well when I want to allocate less than the size of a page.

But I don't understand how I am supposed to deal the allocation of something which **is larger than the size of a page**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default libc malloc implementation *already* allocates large single allocations of memory using `mmap` and `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

To demonstrate, compile this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  void *i = malloc (100 * 1024 * 1024);
  exit (0);
}
```

Then run it under `strace`:

```
$ strace ./x 2>&1

execve("./x", ["./x"], [/* 21 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x135d000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ad0fbb000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=105169, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 105169, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ad0fa1000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\30\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1811128, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3925176, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ad09dc000
mprotect(0x7f7ad0b91000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ad0d90000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b4000) = 0x7f7ad0d90000
mmap(0x7f7ad0d96000, 17592, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ad0d96000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ad0fa0000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ad0f9f000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ad0f9e000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f7ad0f9f700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ad0d90000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ad0fbd000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f7ad0fa1000, 105169)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 104861696, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7aca5db000
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

This line ...

```
mmap(NULL, 104861696, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7aca5db000
```

... is the allocation of the large block.

And there lies the answer to your question. You allocate it with a large size and `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

From the man page for `malloc`

> Normally, `malloc()` allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the
>   size of the heap as required, using `sbrk`(2).  When allocating blocks
>   of memory larger than `MMAP_THRESHOLD` bytes, the glibc `malloc()`
>   implementation allocates the memory as a private anonymous mapping
>   using `mmap(2)`.  `MMAP_THRESHOLD` is 128 kB by default, but is
>   adjustable using `mallopt(3)`.  Allocations performed using `mmap`(2) are
>   unaffected by the `RLIMIT_DATA` resource limit (see `getrlimit`(2)).

And from the man page for `mallopt`

> `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD`
>
> When  an  allocation  request  larger  than the given value cannot be satisfied by an existing free chunk, the memory is guaranteed to be obtained with mmap(). Smaller requests might be allocated with either of `mmap()` or `sbrk()`. `mmap()`-allocated memory can be immediately returned to the OS when it is freed, but this is not true for all memory allocated with `sbrk()`; however, memory allocated by `mmap()` and later freed is neither joined nor reused, so the overhead is greater.  Default: 128*1024.
>
> `M_MMAP_MAX`
>
> The given value sets the maximum number of `mmap()`-allocated chunks allowed to be in use at a given time (even if the size of the allocation request exceeds the value of the `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD` parameter).  This is useful on systems where the `mmap()` implementation scales poorly. A value of 0 disables the use of `mmap()`.  Default: 65536.

If you tune `M_MMAP_TRESHOLD` down to zero (I don't know if it would work that far), I would guess every allocation is going to be done via `mmap`, without you changing more than one line of code. But in any event, the answer to your question is `mmap` with similar parameters to the above.

Note that it may be undesirable to have too many individual `mmap`'d areas, in which case you will want to allocate within a single area or multiple areas. Growing `mmap` areas without changing their address may prove hard, and this may make returning memory to the OS difficult when allocations are fragmented.